# Group by and count conditional values in pandas / python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, conditional-statements

Please, I need count two independents columns with conditional values in my python / pandas code.
See the example using lambda:

```
self._df = self._df.groupby(['id', 'field1', 'field2'])['fieldX', 'fieldY'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([(x['fieldX'] == 1).sum(), (x['fieldY'] == 2).sum()])).reset_index()
```

This code is slow.
Is there another way with pandas and group by without lambda?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. First use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for compare both columns, convert to integers and assign columns back to original, so last need only aggregate `sum`:

```
self._df = (self._df.assign(fieldX = (self._df['fieldX'] == 1).astype(int),
                            fieldY = (self._df['fieldY'] == 2).astype(int))
                    .groupby(['id', 'field1', 'field2'])['fieldX', 'fieldY']
                    .sum()
                    .reset_index())
```